# Can I find the kernel for convolution given that I have the input image and the result in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, convolution

For eg, I know image I and its result J. I need to find out the kernel that was applied on I to get J.

Comment: @obchardon, I'm sorry.. I don't know where to start.. I tried using deconv()..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19150516/2d-deconvolution-using-fft-in-matlab-problems

Answer (score 1):

I think we'd need a bit more information to be able to give some guidance here.

The short story is that if what you have is the result of a circular convolution (i.e., something like `y = ifft2(fft2(x).*fft2(h))`, then you can use the FFT to recover the kernel by just inverting this process (though there may be numerical concerns if `fft2(x)` or `fft2(h)` have any elements close to zero.

However, my guess would be that you have the partial result of a linear convolution -- something like having `y = conv2(x, h, 'same')`.  In this case, you need to solve a two-level Toeplitz system `y = T*h`, where `T` is the convolution matrix constructed from `x`.